# Branch.io: Generating batch content reference for app indexing

Tags: ios, branch.io

I'm building a LBS app which lists 5000+ locations for people to search for.

I want those locations to [be searchable](https://docs.branch.io/pages/organic-search/firebase/) on Google as well, so that people clicking on links from google will get directed to open my app if it's installed.

The question is do I have to generate a [Branch Universal Object](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#create-content-reference) for each location out there? If so, should I be generating those objects at once every time my app gets launched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You will have to generate Branch Universal Object for each location and you should be doing it every time the user performs a share action.

```
let lp: BranchLinkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
lp.channel = "facebook"
lp.feature = "sharing"
lp.campaign = "content 123 launch"
lp.stage = "new user"
lp.tags = ["one", "two", "three"]

lp.addControlParam("$desktop_url", withValue: "http://example.com/desktop")
lp.addControlParam("$ios_url", withValue: "http://example.com/ios")
lp.addControlParam("$ipad_url", withValue: "http://example.com/ios")
lp.addControlParam("$android_url", withValue: "http://example.com/android")
lp.addControlParam("$match_duration", withValue: "2000")

lp.addControlParam("custom_data", withValue: "yes")
lp.addControlParam("look_at", withValue: "this")
lp.addControlParam("nav_to", withValue: "over here")
lp.addControlParam("random", withValue: UUID.init().uuidString) 

buo.showShareSheet(with: lp, andShareText: message, from: self) { (activityType, completed) in
  print(activityType ?? "")
}
```

Also, Let me break down the SEO indexing in two points:

1. When you create a Branch links using the Branch Universal Object, i.e when you request to generate a link on our Branch servers, we receive all the link data and you receive back a Branch link. Now, as we have all the data related to the Branch link, it can be added in the sitemap.

Flow: 
Request to generate Branch link -> Send link data to Branch server -> Branch server sends back the link -> Link added for sitemap generation

2. As we have generated the sitemap, to index the Branch links hosted on your domain Branch requires some engagement on the links. What this means is, to index the link and its content in the Google search ranking Branch links require some actions to be performed on them to create index rankings for the links having engagements.

Flow: 
Branch link(already in the sitemap) -> Shared on media platform -> Users click on the link -> Google starts indexing the link in the search results

Below are the steps to getting started with the indexing:

1. Add the Branch SDK: You can check out the documentation as per your platform here: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/
2. Setup Deep Link Routing: You would need to deep link the user to the specific content in the app when clicked o the Branch link. Please refer to our documentation here: You can check out the documentation here https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#navigate-to-content
3. Add Branch Link Sharing: Please refer to our documentation here to generate shareable links here: https://docs.branch.io/pages/viral/content-sharing/#generate-shareable-links
4. Enable App Indexing on the Branch Dashboard: Once everything is set up, you would now need to enable App Indexing on the Branch dashboard as mentioned in the docs here: https://docs.branch.io/pages/organic-search/firebase/#overview

Also, please do note that Branch link indexing is mostly useful if you do not have a mobile web, otherwise Google will always prioritize your mobile webpages in web ranking over Branch links.

Comment: Thanks Bharath! So the basic flow would be: generate a link for a location > share it on social media > have someone clicks on it. But how do I know if it actually gets indexed by Google? By check the dashboard status?